# How to output the members of list items?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in the C# and .NET at all. 
So, I have a collection that contains objects

```
private List<object> trains = new List<object>();
...
trains.Add(trains[0]);
trains.Add(trains[1]);
trains.Add(trains[2]);
trains.Add(trains[3]);
trains.Add(trains[4]);
```

And later in my code I must to input all elements of my collection 
I'm trying something like that, but it doesn't work

```
public void Display()
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i<trains.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(trains[i].Number); 
        Console.WriteLine(trains[i].Destination);
    } 
}
```

Help me please, I'm really dont understand how to input it to the console. I read Microsoft documentation about the "List" but :(

Comment: Use a `List<Train>` instead of a `List<Object>`.

Comment: As a tip for writing good questions you should never just say something "doesn't work". You should describe what it does and what you expect it to do to make sure we know what is happening. What you expect is pretty clear but "it doesn't work" could cover anything from compile time failure to runtime exception thrown to it just outputting "I am a banana" instead of the number and destination expected. Make it easy for us to help you by giving us all the information you have on how its going wrong. Luckily trained operatives like Tim are good at spotting errors with minimal info. :)

Comment: "trained operatives" - love it!

Comment: In this case I will prefer ArrayList class. Then you can do this: `foreach (train_type t in trains) { Console.WriteLine(t.Number); ...}`.

Comment: The title of your post was edited so it better summarizes your question.

Comment: @i486 You can do that with `List<object>` as well.  The casting is baked into `foreach` specifically to handle pre-generics, but also works with generics.

Comment: @Chris: i must copy-paste your comment  for future purposes ;)

Comment: thank you guys! I understood you Chris, thank you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of objects. And `object` class doesn't have those members (`Number` and `Destination`). If you wanna access them either you need to cast your objects to your type or have a list of `Train` instead of `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are storing your objects in a `List<object>`, Since your class *(probably named)* `Train` inherit from `Object`, you can store *its* object in `object`. You need `List<Train>` and then you can access each member property like:

```
private List<Train> trains = new List<Train>();
```

If you can do that for some reason then you have to explicitly cast your object to `Train` like:

```
Console.WriteLine(((Train)(trains[i])).Number);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this

```
class Train
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
}
```

And that you are doing something like this:

```
var t1 = new Train();
t1.Number = 1;
t1.Destination = "somewhere";
var t2 = new Train();
t2.Number = 2;
t2.Destination = "somewhereelse";
trains.Add(t1);
trains.Add(t2);
```

Than you can output using this:

```
Train train;
foreach(object t in trains)
{
    if ((train = t as Train) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Number); 
        Console.WriteLine(t.Destination);
    }
}
```

The advantage of using a list of objects is that you can put "anything" there. Not only "Train". But as pointed by @Chris, foreach do not filter, so you have to filter it yourself.

Comment: What would happen in that foreach if you did put something else in there that wasn't a `Train`?

Comment: @Chris, Nothing. The foreach will "get" ONLY the objects that can be cast to the one defined, in this case, Train. If you put another object of another type, for example, an object of type "class Car", it will not be retrieved by the looping.

Comment: In my testing (`List<object> foo = new List<Object>(); foo.Add(new Train()); foo.Add(new Car()); foreach (Train train in foo) { }`) it tells me `Unable to cast object of type 'Car' to type 'Train'` which is what I'd expect. For each loops through each object. It doesn't do filtering (as far as I am aware). Your suggestion will work if there are only Trains but the best way to guarantee that is to make sure your list can only contain Trains. And then you don't need your suggestion...

Comment: You're completely right @Chris. I updated the answer. I still think a "object" list is useful, even with the extra code required to filter it :) But maybe not explicitely for the case here. But even if you use a List of Trains the foreach is more clear (in my opinion) than the common for loop. Unless you have to do something tied to the position (index) of the object in the list.

Comment: Yup. I will agree that a foreach is more clear and also that a list of more generic objects can be useful (rarely as generic as object but things like `List<vehicle>` clearly have benefits).

Answer (score 0):

To access the Train object directly, you will need to cast the generic object to a Train object prior to referencing it's exposed properties.  This can be done on the fly, it's not necessary to declare the extra variable myTrain here, however for sake of clarity and readability, I generally do it like this.

```
public void Display()
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i<trains.Count; i++)
    {
        Train myTrain = (Train)trains[i];
        Console.WriteLine(myTrain.Number); 
        Console.WriteLine(myTrain.Destination);
    } 
}
```

Others have mentioned and I would agree, I can think of very few situations where you would NEED to use a:

```
List<object>();
```

rather than:

```
List<Train>();
```

The only thing that jumps out at me would be if you might be storing non Train objects in the same list with Train objects but I cannot think of a good reason to do something like that off the top of my head.

Comment: And if you were storing non-train objects as well then your code would throw an `InvalidCastException` so this isn't a good idea really without putting some guards in. As you say its rarely a good idea to use `List<object>` and if you do then you need to do all the type checking yourself.